# how to hide navigation left and right based on first and last li

Tags: javascript, jquery

**how to hide navigation left and right based on first and last li**

I have developed a slider using jQuery to displays 3 images out of the total number of images.

functions moveRight() and moveLeft() that displays a set of 3 images on clicking the navigation link.

Now i just i want to know how to hide navLeft and navright based on first and last image.

Code is here:-
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Harsh343/Tfy8h/)

```
<script>
        var currentImage = 3;
        var numImages = 0;

        jQuery('.gallery-li').each(function () {
            numImages++;
            if (numImages <= 3) {
                jQuery('.navRight').hide();
                jQuery('.navLeft').hide();
            } else {
                jQuery('.navRight').show();
            }
        });

        jQuery('a.navLeft').click(function () {
            moveLeft();
        });

        jQuery('a.navRight').click(function () {
            moveRight();
        });

    function moveRight() {
     jQuery(".gallery-li").animate({left: "-=380px",}, "slow" );
     jQuery('.navLeft').css('display' , 'block');
    }

    function moveLeft() {
        jQuery(".gallery-li").animate({left: "+=380px",}, "slow" );
    }

</script>
```

**Images inside gallery-li is dynamic**

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to keep a track of your movements and make conditions to the borders to hide the arrows:

Just like this:

```
    var currentImage = 3;
    var numImages = 0;
    var shift = 0;
    var numberOfImagesShiftedByClick = 3;
    var numberOfImagesDisplayed = 5;

    jQuery('.gallery-li').each(function () {
        numImages++;
        if (numImages <= 3) {
            jQuery('.navRight').hide();
            jQuery('.navLeft').hide();
        } else
            $('.navRight').show();
    });

    jQuery('a.navLeft').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    jQuery('a.navRight').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

function moveRight() {
 jQuery(".gallery-li").animate({left: "-=380px",}, "slow" );
 jQuery('.navLeft').css('display' , 'block');
    shift++;
    if (1 + shift*numberOfImagesShiftedByClick + numberOfImagesDisplayed > numImages + 1)
        $("a.navRight").hide();
     $("a.navLeft").show();
}

function moveLeft() {
    jQuery(".gallery-li").animate({left: "+=380px",}, "slow" );
    shift --;
    if (shift == 0)
        $("a.navLeft").hide();
     $("a.navRight").show();
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle to show you this code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Tfy8h/24/

Comment: Adjust the conditions on the variable `shift` to your taste.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues finding the correct values for `shift`

Comment: can we make shift according to numImages , because i want to make it more dynamic. hope u understand

Comment: because sometime shift would be 2 or 3 or 4 or anything. In some case i have 2,3,4 and so on. so i cannot fixed it otherwise if would he hardcoded. Thanks allots.

Comment: Just edited my answer to make it dynamic according to `numImages`. Here is a new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tfy8h/24/ The link is also available from the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work (http://jsfiddle.net/QG9m4):

```
    var currentImage = 0;
    var numImages = jQuery('.gallery-li').length;

    jQuery('a.navLeft').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    jQuery('a.navRight').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

function updateNav() {
  var hideLeft = currentImage == 0;
  var hideRight = currentImage == numImages;

 if( hideLeft )
   jQuery('.navLeft').hide();
 else
   jQuery('.navLeft').show();

 if( hideRight )
   jQuery('.navRight').hide();
 else
   jQuery('.navRight').show();        
}

function moveRight() {
 if( currentImage >= numImages )
   return;        
 currentImage += 3;
 jQuery(".gallery-li").animate({left: "-=380px",}, "slow" );
 jQuery('.navLeft').css('display' , 'block');
 updateNav();
}

function moveLeft() {
    if( currentImage < 1 )
      return;
    currentImage -= 3;
    jQuery(".gallery-li").animate({left: "+=380px",}, "slow" );
    updateNav();
}
```

Comment: This needs a little fix, the right arrow does not hide when you reach the end. But it's fine for the left one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var current = 3;
var numImages = $('.gallery-li').length;

jQuery('a.navLeft').click(function () {
    move();
});

jQuery('a.navRight').click(function () {
    move("right");
});
function move(d){
    if(d == "right"){
        current += 3;
        $(".gallery-li").animate({left: "-=380px",}, "slow" );
    }else{
        current -= 3;
        $(".gallery-li").animate({left: "+=380px",}, "slow" );
    }
    $(".navRight, .navLeft").show();
    if(current == 0) $(".navLeft").hide();
    if(current >=  numImages) $(".navRight").hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tfy8h/22/